# Get active month, day, and year in full calendar in Angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am working on full calendar where i want to get the current active month, year and day in full calendar on click of next and previous buttons.

[image]

```
  events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {  
        
        console.log(fetchInfo.startStr);
        console.log(fetchInfo.endStr);
```

in callback method able to get start and end date but it is starting from 28th August but i want start date like 1st september 2023

Comment: You can simply add a day to `endStr`: `let newEndStr = new Date(new Date(fetchInfo.endStr).getTime() + (24 * 14) * 60 * 60 * 1000);`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi that appears to be entirely unrelated to the question!

Answer (score 0):

To get the date range in the callback to be only the month itself when fetching events for the month view, you can set

```
showNonCurrentDates: false
```

Documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/showNonCurrentDates